# Enabling checkbox with Javascript

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm trying to use a bookmarklet to check and uncheck certain check boxes. However, the method the check boxes are created seems a little unconventional.

```
<DIV class=criteriaSelectorSection id=EntityContatiner>
    <DIV id=EntityContainer_Checked>
        <DIV><INPUT id="c_Checkbox2" onclick=HandleClick(this); type=checkbox CHECKED value=""><LABEL title="Checkbox2">Checkbox 2</LABEL></DIV>
    </DIV>
    <DIV id=EntityContainer_Unchecked>
        <DIV class=cIControls><INPUT id="u_Checkbox1" onclick=HandleClick(this); type=checkbox CHECKED value=""><LABEL title="Checkbox 1">Checkbox 1</LABEL></DIV>
        <DIV class=cIControls style="DISPLAY: none"><INPUT id="u_Checkbox2" onclick=HandleClick(this); type=checkbox CHECKED value=""><LABEL title="Checkbox 2">Checkbox 2</LABEL></DIV>
    </DIV>
</DIV>
```

When a check box is clicked, it seems to not change its value (in the DOM) until the search button is clicked. Its style in the unchecked div is set to not display. Similarly, if it is disabled by the user, it "moves" (via ASP.NET/Ajax) to the unchecked div.

I have tried `document.getElementById("u_Checkbox1").checked = true;`, `document.getElementById("u_Checkbox1").enabled = true;`, and `document.getElementById("u_Checkbox1").Click()`. However, none of these seem to register. Thanks for any help.

Comment: That is called invalid markup generation. You can't assign same ids to multiple elements in a single page.

Comment: You can use on change function - onchange=HandleClick(this)   
http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/aZBNWr

Comment: @Jai Yes, you are right. The page appends u_ and c_ (unchecked and checked) to the id's. However, the same issue exists.

Comment: @Naga Sai A This seems to alert when the user manually makes a change. However, I am looking to have Javascript enabled/disable the checkbox. Am I mistaken?

Comment: document.getElementById('Checkbox2').disabled=true;

Comment: Don't see any elements with same id here. Output the value of your checkbox to the console to see how it is changing and to check its checked value.

Comment: updated codepen with same

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable this control, you should use...

```
document.getElementById("u_Checkbox1").disabled = false;
```

There is no enabled property, counter-intuitive as this is.